# Aurelia: templating. Include a template in another

Tags: layout, aurelia, templating

I would like to use two layouts for my Aurelia app.
Home - FAQ - Login page don't contain a sidebar;
But everything else do contain this sidebar.

My architecture, with a sidebar is pretty complicated in HTML and is like:

```
div.container
   div.sidebar
     div.sidebar_content
     div.site_content
```

So i can't just enable or disable the sidebar because it contains the view.
I have to make two pages like "app.html", defined in main.js, but how tell to Aurelia "Choose app.html for this page, and app2.html for this other page"?

I have found the setRoot function but i have bugs with it (the routes does not work properly when i change setroot)
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 2):

The router supports the concept of "layouts." This is documented here: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/10

Basically, you specify a layout for each route (you can specify a default layout on the `router-view` custom element:

**app.html**

```
 <router-view layout-view="./layout-with-sidebar.html"></router-view>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    var model = {
      id: 1
    };
    config.map([
      { route: ['home', ''], name: 'home', title: "Home", moduleId: 'home', nav: true },
      { route: 'no-sidebar', name: 'no-sidebar', title: "No Sidebar", moduleId: 'no-sidebar', nav: true, layoutView: 'layout-without-sidebar.html' }
    ]);
    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

**layout-with-sidebar.html**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <slot name="sidebar"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <slot name="main-content"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**layout-without-sidebar.html**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <slot name="main-content"></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**home.html**

```
<template>
  <div slot="sidebar">
    <p>I'm content that will show up on the right.</p>
  </div>
  <div slot="main-content">
    <p>I'm content that will show up on the left.</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**no-sidebar.html**

```
<template>
  <div slot="main-content">
    <p>Look ma! No sidebar!</p>
  </div>
</template>
```